# Tomar en Angular.js el mes de una variable tipo DateTime

Tags: sql-server, angularjs

Buen Día.
Necesito obtener el mes (ya sea nombre o numero) de una fecha tipo `DateTime`, proveniente de ***SQL Server*** y compararla en ***Angular js***.

La fecha a la que me refiero viene de la siguiente forma: **"2019-04-20T00:00:00-03:00"**. La idea es poder hacer un filtro en base al mes, por lo que necesito poder comparar el mes que viene en dicha fecha contra el mes que seleccione el usuario.
Probé con funciones como :

```
var utc1 = Date.UTC(vencimiento.getFullYear(), vencimiento.getMonth(), 
vencimiento.getDate())
```

Donde Vencimiento tiene el formato **"2019-04-20T00:00:00-03:00"**. Pero me tira que los `getFullYear` no es una función.

Resumo lo mas posible para que se entienda. Me llaga una variable con la fecha "2019-04-20T00:00:00-03:00" quiero extraer el mes, a través de ***angularjs.***

Comment: Dices que te llega la variable de fecha como un`string`, ¿Porqué intentas usar funciones de un tipo `Date` en un `string`? Tal vez un simple `substring()` haga el trabajo que quieres sobre tu variable `vencimiento`. Saludos

Comment: Si correcto, Me llega a través de un llamado de APi que trae la variable desde una BD SQL Server , en la cual dicha variable tiene el tipo DateTime. Al llegar a Angular lo toma como un string.

Comment: El tipo `DateTime` es propio de SQL Server, cuando recibes el valor de dicho dato, es una representación en `string` del mismo. Para Angular (Javascript), es un tipo `string`. Debes manipularlo como tal. Tu estás manipulándolo como si se tratara de un tipo `Date`. Ese es el problema. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio excelente, no terminaba de razonar algo tan simple como lo que mencionas. Te agradezco por la ayuda. Saludos.